# Can each mobile app have its own client account for payments? (Windows Phone, Android and iPhone)

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, iso

My company has many clients wanting mobile applications and having the payments come into our account and then sorting the payments would be a real pain.
So can a company have a main account to publish applications (free and chargeable) and still have some sort of client account for each app (so they could view sales and receive full payment directly)?

I would like to know for Windows, Android and Apple please.

Answer (score 1):

For `maintainability and ease of communication` back with customers, i am strongly recommending to create different accounts for FREE and commercial apps that you are publishing to marketplace.

At least in Windows marketplace, if you keep adding your apps from one account, you may end-up with hundreds of feedback and emails without a glue (do i need to urgently support this or not?) from where (paid /free app) it comes from.

Comment: Wouldn't I just end up with loads of account and have to pay the account charge each time? Thanks for the info though